# Detect Horizontal Touch Event in iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, touch

Is it possible to detect a horiztonal touch event in JavaScript or JQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean a swipe? http://plugins.jquery.com/project/swipe

Answer (score 0):

If you understand how to read touch events, you can check the distance between touch start and current position. If touch end occurs before a minimum distance (your choice) then you can consider it a button click. If it is longer then you can consider it a swipe.

You can also use a directional delta to see the most likely direction intended (vertical or horizontal)

While not a complete answer, I hope this provides some clues to enhance your google-fu...

Answer (score 0):

**Shameless self-plug** > https://github.com/benmajor/jQuery-Mobile-Events